# Как указать Gson`у, чтобы он использовал именно мой сериализатор/десериализатор?

Tags: java, json, gson

Написал собственный конвертер, зарегистрировал в `GsonBuilder'е`. Но отрабатывает только сериализатор и только в одном "rest-методе".

То есть, он работает, но работает сериализация и десериализация по умолчанию, а мой конвертер работает только при сериализации одного метода, когда получаю список объектов, в остальных случаях игнорируется. **В логах ошибок нет**, тихо и не правильно работает, не знаю уже что делать. Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с таким, что не так идет?

Наверно это лишнее, но всё же распишу подробнее.

Провайдер для `gson'а`.

Класс **GsonJsonProvider.java**

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class GsonJsonProvider implements MessageBodyReader<Object>, MessageBodyWriter<Object>{

//---
//инициализация gson и его настроек
private Gson getGson(){
    if (gson == null) {
        gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(UUID.class, new UUIDConverter())
                .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new DateTimeConverter())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Note.class, new NoteConverter())
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .serializeNulls()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        System.err.println("Gson Initialization");
    }
    System.err.println("Gson work");
    return gson;
}
//---
//метод getGson вызывается в этих методах и больше нигде
public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, UTF_8);
    try {
        Type jsonType;
        if (type.equals(genericType)) {
            jsonType = type;
        } else {
            jsonType = genericType;
        }
        return getGson().fromJson(streamReader, jsonType);
    } finally {
        streamReader.close();
    }
}

//----
public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8);
    try {
        Type jsonType;
        if (type.equals(genericType)) {
            jsonType = type;
        } else {
            jsonType = genericType;
        }
        getGson().toJson(object, jsonType, writer);
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Класс модель **Note.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
@NamedQuery(name = "Note.getAll", query = "SELECT n FROM Note n ORDER BY n.id ASC")
public class Note extends Model{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_post")
private int id;
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
private UUID uuid;
private String title;
private String text;
private String password;
private LocalDateTime date;
private int status;
//---
```

Класс конвертер **NoteConverter.java**

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(Note note, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {

    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    result.add("uuid", context.serialize(note.getUuid()));
    result.addProperty("title", note.getTitle());
    result.addProperty("text", note.getText());
    result.addProperty("password", note.getPassword() != null ? note.getPassword() : "null_password");
    result.add("date", context.serialize(note.getDate()));
    result.addProperty("status", note.getStatus());

    return result;
}
```

и

```
@Override
public Note deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

    Note note = new Note();
    note.setUuid(context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("uuid"), UUID.class));
    note.setTitle(jsonObject.get("title").getAsString());
    note.setText(jsonObject.get("text").getAsString());
    note.setPassword(jsonObject.get("password").getAsString());
    note.setDate(context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("date"), LocalDateTime.class));
    note.setStatus(jsonObject.get("status").getAsInt());

    return note;
}
```

Класс **NoteResource.java**

```
//вот здесь мой сериализатор отрабатывает, 
//отдаёт список объектов, где поле date в миллисекундах.
//в логах светится "Gson work" тот, что в GsonJsonProvider.java 
@GET
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Response getAll(){
    List<Note> noteList = dao.getAll("Note.getAll", noteClass);
    return Response.ok(noteList).build();
}

//а здесь, работает сериализация по умолчанию
//и в логах "Gson work" не выходит, то есть он вообще не при делах, почему???
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Response getNote(@PathParam("id") int id){
    Note note = dao.getById(id, noteClass);
    return Response.ok(note).build();
}

//и здесь тоже самое, сам объект note приходит
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addNote(Note note){
    StatusResponse response = new StatusResponse();
    if (note == null) { //эту проверку проходит
        System.err.println("Added, note null!");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(response).build();
    }
    System.err.println("Added, note title: " + note.getTitle());
    System.err.println("Added, uuid: " + note.getUuid());
//а здесь uuid = null, так как не знает как десериализовывать тип UUID
//------
```

**UPDATE**

Добавил параметризацию в класс **GsonJsonProvider.java**

```
public class GsonJsonProvider<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T>, MessageBodyWriter<T> {
//...
```

Метод `readFrom`

```
public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, UTF_8);
    try {
        //с genericType так же не работает
        return getGson().fromJson(streamReader, type);
    } finally {
        streamReader.close();
    }
}
```

Метод `writeTo`

```
public void writeTo(T t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8);
    try {
        //если указывать type вместо genericType, то не работает
        getGson().toJson(t, genericType, writer);
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}

//Сериализация работает как надо, только
//если изменить сеттер в модели Note.java
//но тогда вылетает ошибка при десериализации
//java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.UUID cannot be cast to java.lang.String
public void setUuid(String uuidString) {
    this.uuid = UUID.fromString(uuidString);
}

//а с таким(нормальным) сеттером
//и сер/десериализация не работает (без ошибок в логах)
public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}
```

Comment: а вы сделайте `Ctrl+B` на методе `registerTypeAdapter`. мне кажется он не добавляет, а заменяет адаптеры. В итоге срабатывает последний. Если это так, то вам нужны разные `GSON` и возможно разные `Retrofit`

Comment: не могу представить, как это выглядит, где вызывать новый gson? Он у меня инициализируется в одном месте и вызывается же где то под капотом аннотаций jax-rs, вроде как

Comment: можно пример как это выглядит?

Comment: Метод `reqisterTypeAdapter` внутри у себя добавляет адаптеры в список, `this.factories.add(TreeTypeAdapter.newFactoryWithMatchRawType(typeToken, typeAdapter));`

Comment: ой, тогда простите, значит проблема в другом

Comment: Покажите как вы объявляете `NoteConverter.java`. И где вы указали, чтобы при сериализации использовался именно ваш `Gson`?

Comment: Объявляется только в `GsonJsonProvider'e`, при регистрации в `GsonBuilder'e`, больше нигде не указывается. Думал он видит не известный тип и ищет ему обработчик у меня.

Comment: Как же указать, чтобы использовался именно мой `Gson`?

Comment: Покажите код вызова сериализации/десериализации gson

Comment: Нет такого, думаю это я и ищу

Comment: Я немного не понимаю как работает gson в связке с jax-rs. Когда указываю аннотации `Produces/Consumes`, что в это время происходит? Думал gson сам понимает, когда его выход на сцену, так как его класс-настройка помечается аннотацией `Provider`. Но нет. Я нигде не вызываю отдельно сер/десериализцаю, так как полагаюсь на эти аннотации. И если их и нужно вызывать вручную,я не представляю как это сделать, где их вызывать, в каком месте.Если я отправляю json данные `post` запросом, то аннотация `Consumes` запускает сериализацию по умолчанию.Как мне её опередить или подсунуть туда свой gson.

Comment: Вот, непонимаю как они(`gson/jax-rs`) устроены в связке

Comment: `private Gson getGson()` потом где-то вызывается?

Comment: Ну, только внутри класса, где он определен, в методах `readFrom/writeTo` интерфейсов `MessageBodyReader/Writer`, обновил вопрос с кодом класса `GsonJsonProvider.java`

Comment: Покажите как вы вызываете `readFrom()/writeTo()` - похоже собака зарыта там

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в куске:

```
if (type.equals(genericType)) {
        jsonType = type;
    } else {
        jsonType = genericType;
    }
```

У вас на выходе тип всегда будет `genericType`, то есть адаптер никогда не вызовется, поскольку вы всегда вызываете Gson с дженерик типом.

Comment: Попытался, что то с этим сделать, обновил вопрос